# Clear all sessions for single user

Tags: node.js, redis, passport.js

On my site, I would like a form where the administrator of an organization is able to reset a users password. Ideally, when this resets, I would like to clear all recognized sessions for that user from my RedisStore that holds session data for express and passport. Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can find items by key from Redis fast, but since the data needed to identify correct sessions is in the values you would need to go through all keys and see which ones belong to the user in question.

You could store session IDs to sets by username when they login, and then when you need to delete the session you would just get the keys from the list and delete them, and then delete the list.

```
var client = redis.createClient();
// Add the session ID to a set (if not there already)
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback: true}, function (req, username, password, cb) {
  // Do normal login stuff first. 
  // RedisStore adds 'sess:' to session ID when making it a key
  client.sadd("sessions:" + user.username, "sess:" + req.session.id);
  cb(null, user);
}));
```

Then to delete the sessions:

```
var deleteSessions = function(username, cb) {
  client.smembers("sessions:" + username, function(err, sessionIds) {
    if (sessionIds.length === 0) return cb();
    // Delete all sessions
    client.del.apply(client, sessionIds);
    // Delete the set containing now deleted session IDs
    client.del("sessions:" + username);
    cb();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@vesse 's solution is a good way to solve this, however, in his case the new sessionId would get added to the Set only when calling `passport.authenticate()` (which is normally only used on '/login' route) and not on every login.

If you login user on multiple routes, using `req.login()` in multiple places, you should add the new sessionId to the Set in `serializeUser`, which gets called anytime you call `passport.authenticate()` or `req.login()`.

```js
// passing in req: https://github.com/jwalton/passport-api-docs#passportserializeuserfnuser-done--fnreq-user-done
passport.serializeUser(function (req, user, done) {
    // Track user's open sessionIds, by saving them under userId-key as a Set
    client.sAdd('sessions:' + user._id, 'sess:' + req.session.id);

    done(null, user._id);
});
```